# I have error : InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type while attempting to activate controller

Tags: c#, entity-framework, model-view-controller, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-6

I have error when I make web app with EF 6.0.

> ```
> InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'WebbyMyself.Models.StudentManageEntities' while attempting to activate 'WebbyMyself.Controllers.BranchesController'.
> ```

It has ***Models/StudentManageEntities.cs***:

> ```
> using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
>
> namespace WebbyMyself.Models
> {
>     public class StudentManageEntities : DbContext
>     {
>         protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBulder)
>         {
>             optionsBulder.UseSqlServer(
>                 "*connetion string of my database*"
>             );
>         }
>         public virtual DbSet<Branch> Branch { get; set; }
>     }
> }
> ```

And ***Controllers/BranchController.cs:***

> ```
> using System;
> using System.Collections.Generic;
> using System.Linq;
> using System.Threading.Tasks;
> using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
> using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering;
> using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
> using WebbyMyself.Models;
>
> namespace WebbyMyself.Controllers
> {
>     public class BranchController : Controller
>     {
>         private readonly StudentManageEntities _context;
>
>         public BranchController(StudentManageEntities context)
>         {
>             _context = context;
>         }
>
>         // GET: Branch
>         public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
>         {
>               return View(await _context.Branch.ToListAsync());
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```

And ***Views/Branch/Index.cshtml***:

> ```
> @model IEnumerable<WebbyMyself.Models.Branch>
>
> @{
>     ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
> }
>
> <h1>Index</h1>
>
> <p>
>     <a asp-action="Create">Create New</a>
> </p>                            
> <table class="table">
>     <thead>
>         <tr>
>             <th>
>                 @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.BranchName)
>             </th>
>             <th></th>
>         </tr>
>     </thead>
>     <tbody>
> @foreach (var item in Model) {
>         <tr>
>             <td>
>                 @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.BranchName)
>             </td>
>             <td>
>                 <a asp-action="Edit" asp-route-id="@item.ID">Edit</a> |
>                 <a asp-action="Details" asp-route-id="@item.ID">Details</a> |
>                 <a asp-action="Delete" asp-route-id="@item.ID">Delete</a>
>             </td>
>         </tr>
> }
>     </tbody>
> </table>
> ```

I use Code Generation in Visual Studio 2022.

I don't know how to fix, so pls help me.

I don't know how to describe so if you want more information pls tell me. Thank you so much.

Comment: And have you registered it in the DI (if later framework used - in the Program file)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to register your DbContext class with name "StudentManageEntities" like this on Program.cs file:

```
services.AddDbContext<StudentManageEntities>();
```

or like this:

```
services.AddDbContext<StudentManageEntities>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(@"Your connection string"));
```